# Google Sheets API v4 Appending data getting bad request 400 error

Tags: java, android, google-sheets-api

I am trying to append Sheets row, I am trying to put 2 Strings in single row in 2 columns.

Here is the code:

```java
String range = "Write!A2:E200";
String spreadsheetId = SPREADSHEET_ID;
List<List<Object>> values = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList());

ValueRange body = new ValueRange().setValues(values);
AppendValuesResponse result = service.spreadsheets()
    .values()
    .append(spreadsheetId, range, body)
    .setValueInputOption("USER_ENTERED")
    .execute();
```

When I try to to add:

```java
values.add(new ArrayList<Object>(ListOfMyTwoStrings));
```

I am getting the null error.

**Update:**

I have added:

```
List<Object> lists = new ArrayList<>();
lists.add(ListOne);
lists.add(ListTwo);

List<List<Object>> values = new ArrayList<>();
values.add(lists);
```

Where `ListOne` and `ListTwo` are `List<String>` with the data which I want to append in the sheet, but when I try to execute I am getting:

```
400 Bad Request
{
  "code":400,
  "errors":[
    {
      "domain":"global",
      "message":"Invalid values[1][0]: list_value {\n}\n",
      "reason":"badRequest"
    }
  ],
  "message":"Invalid values[1][0]: list_value {\n}\n",
  "status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

Can someone please help me to fix it?
Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: This error usually happens when you have the wrong array format. As stated in these related threads [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44301642/upload-values-to-google-sheets) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38901386/google-sheet-api-batch-update-issue-ios/38903260), it should be in the form of `[[ 'a', 'b', 'c'], [ 1, 2, 3 ]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution, this is working for me:

```java
List<Object> lists = new ArrayList<>();

lists.add("String 1");
lists.add("String 2");

List<List<Object>> values = new ArrayList<>();
values.add(lists);
```

This will append "String 1" to A1 and "String 2" to A2.

Thanks abielita for tip.