# Google sheets API for PHP returns 400 error on append

Tags: php, api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to append data at the end of my spread sheet but i'm getting the following error

> Google_Service_Exception: {   "error": {     "code": 400,
>   "message": "Invalid values[1716][0]: struct_value {\n  fields {\n
>   key: \"0\"\n

This is my code:

```
$conf = ["valueInputOption" => "USER_ENTERED"];

$data[] = array($projects[0]);
$projects_data = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange(array(
    'values' => $data
  ));             
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->append($spreadsheetId, $range, $projects_data, $conf);
```

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44865360/google-sheets-api-v4-appending-data-getting-bad-request-400-error). You will encounter this error when you have the wrong array format. Try in the form of `[[ 'a', 'b', 'c'], [ 1, 2, 3 ]]`. Here's an additional link for reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-spreadsheets-api/c3wGF7nWJn4

Comment: @abielita Thank you it helps i just changed it to the following code and it works now.

'values' => array(self::getFormattedData($projects[$i]))

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the data was not in proper format. I changed the code to following and it works.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($projects); $i++) {
  $projects_data = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange(array(
    'values' => array(self::getFormattedData($projects[$i]))
  ));             
  $response = $service->spreadsheets_values->append($spreadsheetId, $range, $projects_data, $conf);
}    
public static function getFormattedData($data) {
    $ret = implode(',',$data);

    return explode(',',$ret);
}
```